# Xcode 5.1.1 not compiling the project

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

`Xcode 5.1.1` is taking infinite time to run the project. 
Project just waits infinitely at **"Generating dSYM file"** status.

I tried updating `"DWARF with dSYM file"` with `"DWARF"`
It again waits for ages showing status `"Processing 'info.plist' file"` in the Xcode top bar.

In the end. I could not compile the file.

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Did it happen on all projects ?

Comment: No It didn't. We are using third party library .a file as a engine for hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your info.plist is not corrupt. In past I've manually edited such files and got similar problems (git merge conflicts).

General answer: you could use [git bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to go to last compiling version and then check what has changed since then.

Comment: Thanks. But there isn't any update with code. We even the tried compiling and running last final working copy of the project. But end up with the same issue.

Comment: Should not be possible, something must have changed. Are ALL FILES under version control, not only source code? Did you install Xcode beta and overwrite tools selection (Settings - Location - Command Line Tools)